# How can i perform task even if the app is closed in React Native

Tags: android-service, react-native

I want to perform some task if the device is back online. I have tried with Broadcast receiver but its working perfectly when the app is running and the app is moved to background. but its not working when the app is closed :(.

please find the below code which i have tried..

```
import {DeviceEventEmitter,Platform} from 'react-native';
const func=(map)=>{
  console.log("connection changed")
}
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('GReferrerBroadcastReceiver', func);
```

Can anyone propose a solution for how to perform some task if the app is closed. I found Job scheduler in native android but how can i connect to React Native???

a help will be really appreciable :) ......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This library implement's background tasks. It's implementation is in JS and pretty easy to use: https://github.com/Rapsssito/react-native-background-actions

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score -2):

React-native-background-action works pretty well refer documentation from officially website but if u are looking for user tracking after start click then it fail after 10-15 minutes on phone lock...